# If $f′(x) \ne 0$ for every $x ∈ (a, b)$, then $f$ is injective and onto an open interval $I ⊆ R$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $a$ and $b$ be real numbers such that $a < b$ and let $f : (a, b) → R$
be a differentiable function.

Show that:

If $f′(x) \ne 0$ for every $x ∈ (a, b)$, then $f$ is injective and onto an open
interval $I ⊆ R$.

I have proved the injective part, however I am having trouble with the ''onto an open interval '' part.

Comment: Since $f$ is differentiable, it is also continuous. The image of a connected set, e.g. an open interval, under a continuous map is also connected. $f$ is strictly monotone since its derivative is strictly positive (or strictly negative), so the intermediate value theorem yields that the image of $(a,b)$ under $f$ is also an open interval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $I=f\bigl((a,b)\bigr)\subseteq \Bbb R$ be the image of $f$, let $u=\inf I$, $v=\sup I$ (where possibly $u=-\infty$ and/or $v=+\infty$). We need to show that $I=(u,v)$, that is three claims:

- If $u<y<v$, then $y\in I$
- $u\notin I$
- $v\notin I$

For the first, if $u<y<v$, then by the definition of $\inf$ and $\sup$, there exist $y_1,y_2\in I$ with $u<y_1<y<y_2<v$. If $y_{i}=f(x_{i})$, we can use the IVT to find $x$ between $x_1$ and $x_2$ with $f(x)=y$.

For the second, note that for $x\in (a,b)$ we conclude that $f(\xi)<f(x)$ for $\xi\approx x$ and on the "correct" side of $x$ (depending on the sign of $f'(x)$). Therefore, $I$ contains vaues $<f(x)$ and $f(x)\ne\inf I$ for all $x\in(a,b)$.

The third follows by the same argument.